# LIst of lists python - referencing particular locations / slicing sublists

Tags: python, list, slice, nested-lists, python-itertools

I have a largeish list of lists (imported from a CSV), with a header row. The first three lines, including the header look like this.  There are a lot more elements in each row, but I've truncated it for readability.

```
[('Div', 'Date', 'HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam', 'FTHG', 'FTAG'), 
('E0', '18/08/12', 'Arsenal', 'Sunderland', '0', '0'), 
('E0', '18/08/12', 'Fulham', 'Norwich', '5', '0')... ]
```

It's for a hobby football stats package that I had/have in excel and wanted to make web based so I had something real to work on as I learned python.  I have a number of averages I want to calculate, so want to match home team in each row and add the value in whatever column I've selected to the running total so I can work out the average. In really simple terms, everytime the home team matches "Chelsea", say, I want to add it to my running total to calculate the average number of goals they've scored at home.  The data file is very consistent, so I know that particular variables will always be in column 4, or 5 or whatever.

```
def CalcAverageHome(team, column, data_file):
    total = 0
    count = 0
    for team in data:
        if  data[2] == team:
            print data_file[4]
        #total += data[4]
        count += 1
    else:
       pass
    average = total / 5
    return 
print "Here's the Average"
print CalcAverageHome("Chelsea", 4, data)
```

When I run that code, it provides me with the fourth list (top level list), i.e.

```
('E0', '18/08/12', 'QPR', 'Swansea', '0', '5'...
```

I started trying to use `itertools` but even just iterating through the lists to print it as a debugger didn't work (I like to make sure it works as I go)

```
print "Let's try this with itertools" 
def chain(*iterables):
  for it in iterables:
    print it
    for element in it:
        yield element
        print element
chain(data)
```

`data` is the variable that the data from the CSV's been read into, the list of lists.

But this doesn't print anything - I've had a look at the standard documentation on it, but it's not shedding any light.  I simply want to be able to iterate through each sublist, check if the team matches, and if so, do something with the number a few elements along.  I've been looking at this and various solutions for about a day now (over three days), so I'm a bit frustrated.

Comment: This is rather unusual `for team in data: if  data[2] == team:...` what do you think it does? where is `data` defined?

Comment: Sorry, data is defined previously, I've just added that in an edit.  I wanted to check if the list item in column 2 of data file was the team I was currently looking at.

Comment: ok. I assumed that `data_file` was the list of lists. What is `data_file` then?

Comment: Stupidity on my part, it was supposed to read 'data'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to iterate over the nested lists i think.Also you had wrong variables in the sample code.
I think this works

```
data_file = [('Div', 'Date', 'HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam', 'FTHG', 'FTAG'), 
('E0', '18/08/12', 'Arsenal', 'Sunderland', '0', '0'),
('E0', '18/08/12', 'Arsenal', 'Sunderland', '4', '0'),
('E0', '18/08/12', 'Arsenal', 'Sunderland', '2', '0'),
('E0', '18/08/12', 'Fulham', 'Norwich', '5', '0') ]

def CalcAverageHome(team, column, data_file):
    total = 0
    n=0         # the number of times the team you are looking for is in the data
    for row in data_file:
        if  row[2] == team:
            total += int(row[column])
            n+=1
    try:
        average = float(total) / n  # if u r using python 2.7.Else if 3.2+  just total/n
    except ZeroDivisionError:       # to prevent zerodevisionerror if t team had n games
        average = 'Not played'
    return average
```

The problems were

- that you used ***team*** for iteration over the data_file,which was also the parameter for the calculate function.So in the if check you used inside the for loop,you didn't check for the team you entered in the function but for the row in the data you iterated with the for loop

Comment: Why keep an explicit `count`? can't you use `row` instead of `data_file[count]`?

Comment: yes you are right,i was trying to make the code,more like @chris code.i am editing it now.

Comment: That's lovely (and makes sense, it was referencing the row element I was having problems with) - one question though, it seems to be putting it out as a rounded  integer, which I know isn't right (I assume the actual number is right, it's just rounded).  I'm having that problem with both your mock data set and mine - if I set the third match to '27', the average is 10, when it should be 10.33 recurring.

Comment: What python are you using?if you are using python 2.7 or prior then you have to use average = float(total)/n because  10/3 in python 2.7- returns 3 and not 3.33333.it is integer divisions.If you make the integer to a float,for example 10.0/3 you get 3.33333 .check this [Python Documentation 2.7](http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/introduction.html) for more info.In python 3.2 and later you don't have to do this.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help - I had an old version of python launcher installed and the files were defaulting to launch in 2.7 instead of 3.3 - it's fixed now, thanks!

Comment: It is not about right or wrong version,i am still using 2.7 for myself.A lot of people still do.Just in the next question be specific about the python version you are using because some things differs in each version.Glad i helped.